# F# Code for Adventure Works Sample

Tags: f#, functional-programming, sample, adventureworks

it is very hard to find good samples for **f#** in the web. some samples show a simple web crawler for downloading stock data from yahoo or only code snippets of bigger ideas.

i'm searching for an **real world example outside the financial world**. what about **adventureworks**? the current sample database is the base of many c# samples out there.
why is there now f# sample?

i don't want a sample where f# makes a gui for a table of it! isn't there any f# ideal processing? i like a sample where i can see the power of f#. a sample which show's me why i should learn the language instead of simply using (more code) c#.

- is there any sample for adventure works online?
- are there any real world processes based on the sample database (functional programming)

best regards - michl

Comment: To rephrase your question, "I have a problem (LOB apps) and I want an example of applying a specific solution (F#)". Perhaps the reason there aren't many of examples is that F# isn't the best fit for standard forms-over-data apps. C#/VB have been adding features to support that for years, while F#'s strengths are in algorithmic, data intensive, computationally expensive domains. 

If you search hard enough you'll find a good F# example, but I would suggest you have a specific reason in mind before using F# for any application. (And not just because it's the greatest language ever made ;)

Comment: F# descends from a family of languages that are well suited for writing compilers (so a first real world example would be the F# compiler itself) and programs that work at the symbolic level. My bio contains a link to a program that is not written in F# but could very well have been (it's in OCaml instead). Inside this family of programs F# has the best integration with .NET, so probably that makes it additionally well suited to other problems, but I can't say much about that.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliFactory have some nice samples for how you might build a web UI using F#, the examples are based on their WebSharper product. It's not free but if your serious about building a LOB app in F# then it's definitely worth looking at, as in my humble opinion, it's really good:
http://www.intellifactory.com/products/wsp/Tutorial.aspx#

For the data side I'm told Entity Framework V2 works reasonable well for F#, and there's always my FunctionalNHibernate project which is in it's infancy but really quite cute:
http://bitbucket.org/robertpi/functionalnhibernate/

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpsamples

Comment: yes, i know it. but i think 3DVisualiztion, ConcurrentLife and SolarSystem are not really problems in today's lob-applications. it's much more interesting for research.

webcrawler and excel processing are better examples. but what would a process in advenuture works do, in order to need f# code for it? isn't it better to use something like sql report services instead of f# and excel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I know no AdventureWorks sample in F#, but this might interest you anyways: [wcfstorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx). It is a tool to test WCF services, written in F#.

Comment: cool app, but i'm searching for a process in a standard lob app. until now i only found one good process for f# code: sql-statment generation from webservice-response.